# $pullAll in mongoose doens't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose schema:

```
// ------- creating active_rooms model -------

var active_rooms_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    room_name: String,
    users: [String]
});
var active_rooms = mongoose.model('active_rooms', active_rooms_schema);
```

the DB looks like this:

```
[{"_id":"586b8eeeebb48c65bcbbc5f3","room_name":"my_roome","__v":0,"users":["sam","sally"]}]
```

pretty strightforward. I have a chat room and people (array of user to that room). I want to remove a certain person once he/she exits the room.

therfore, I wrote this code on my server:

```
remove_user_from_room: function (user_name, room_name) {
    console.log("remove_user_from_room: " + room_name + ", user: " + user_name);
    active_rooms.update( {'room_name': room_name }, { $pullAll: {'users': [user_name] } } )
},
```

however, this code doesn't remove a user from the array. it doesn't change the array in my DB.

where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'users'` not  `'user_name'` in the update call?

Comment: my bad, thanks.. updated my answer. but the problem remains :(((

Comment: The update code syntax looks correct, I am guessing maybe its not matching for some reason, can you make a findOne call with {'room_name': room_name } and check if you are getting the correct document or not.

Comment: thanks probelm was that I didn't have promise wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was of lack sync, I needed to use promises.. the code above is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using $pullAll, if you want to remove a single person only.
Use $pull

```
remove_user_from_room: function (user_name, room_name) {
    console.log("remove_user_from_room: " + room_name + ", user: " + user_name);
    active_rooms.update( {'room_name': room_name }, { $pull: {'users': user_name } } )
},
```

Comment: tried your code. still didn't change the active_rooms collection :((